# Email activity on Android

Tags: android, email, gmail

I want to send email from Android virtual machine to my gmail account.
Problem:  but on pressing send button I am getting:

> "No application can perform this action"

Here is my code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
//sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file:///sdcard/mysong.mp3");
//sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/download/test.mp3")); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(GlobalVariable.getstrEmail())); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it on a real device itself, it should work. And you need to change the type:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@example.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: i've set mp3 because i've to send mp3 file with attachment

Answer (score 1):

This can help...

```
  Intent openEmailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  openEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
  openEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                           new String[{"zoombie@gmail.com"});
  openEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject you want");
  openEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Any body ");
  this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openEmailIntent,"Sharing via Email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);        
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailaddress});                                        
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```